# C# Avoid creation of thread when entering method the second time

Tags: c#, multithreading

say we declare and run a thread in a method which has a while(1) loop. How can one avoid to create and run a second thread when the method is called again?
I only want one thread to start in this method and every time the method is called again, there should be no thread creation all over again. Should I check for the thread name or should I declare the thread as a field of the class?

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks,
Juergen

Comment: What is the situation you are trying to model?

Comment: Trivial solutions are creating the thread before you enter the loop, setting a bool flag to indicate that you created it and checking a variable of type Thread for null.

Comment: Not enough information by far. If we have to guess _what_ you want to do, we cannot give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the thread should indeed be a field of the class - although you'll have to be careful to access it in a thread-safe way, if there could be several threads calling the method to start with.

What do you want to happen the second time - should the method block, or just finish immediately, or perhaps throw an exception? If you don't need to wait for the thread to finish, you might be able to get away with just a flag instead of keeping a reference to the thread itself.

(Note that I've been assuming this is an instance method and you want one extra thread *per instance*.) If that's not the case, you'll have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: blimey, that was quick! No sooner had you finished your async talk and it's back to business as usual :)

Comment: @RussCam: That's the benefit of a long train journey back to Reading :)

Comment: @Jon: The second time there should be just a check if the thread was already created. I guess the idea with a static flag to signal an already created thread is fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Juergen: Be careful: it should be a static flag to say that something *has taken responsibility for creating the thread*. It may not have started yet, but you don't want to create two new threads just because two *existing* threads hit the method at the same time, both check the flag and then both decide to create a new thread. You need something like `Interlocked` to do this in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Have the method return a singleton, and start the thread in the singleton constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Could you save the synchronization context the first time, check on subsequent times to see if it matches, and post back to it if necessary?

```
SynchronizationContext syncContext = null;
...

// "object state" is required to be a callback for Post
public void HiThar(object state) { 
  if (syncContext == null) {
    syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  } else {
    syncContext.Post(HiThar, state);
  }
}
```